# FileNotFoundException error while running java program

Tags: java

I am getting a FileNotFoundException while running code.
my filname is filecontent.java...

Definition: I want to create a program having 4 TextFields and 4 TextAreas.  If one types the name of the file in TextField, then its content should be shown in corresponding TextArea.

**Error :**

Exception e : java.io.FileNotFoundException :

**My Code :**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

class filecontent extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    TextField t[]=new TextField[4];
    TextArea ta[]=new TextArea[4];
    Button submit,exit=new Button("Exit");
    Panel p1;
    filecontent()
    {
        setGUI();
        setRegister();
        try{
            showfile();
           }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception e : "+ioe);
        }
        setTitle("FileData");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocation(500,200);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
            { public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
               { System.exit(0); }
            }); 
    }

    void setGUI()
    {
        p1=new Panel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,4,10,10));
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            t[i]=new TextField(10);
            ta[i]=new TextArea();
            p1.add(t[i]);
            p1.add(ta[i]);
        }
        submit=new Button("Submit");
        p1.add(submit);
        p1.add(exit);
    }

    void setRegister()
    {
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
    }

    void showfile() throws java.io.IOException
    {
        FileReader fin[]=new FileReader[4];
        FileReader fn=new FileReader("filecontent.java");
        BufferedReader br[]=new BufferedReader[4];

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {

            fin[i]=new FileReader(t[i].getText());

        }
        int cnt=1;
        String s;
        fn=fin[0];
        br[0]=new BufferedReader(fn);
        while(cnt<=4)
        {
            if((s=br[cnt-1].readLine())!=null) 
            {
                ta[cnt-1].append(s+"");
            }
            else
            {
                fin[cnt-1].close();
                cnt++;
                fn=fin[cnt-1];
                br[cnt-1]=new BufferedReader(fn);
                ta[cnt-1].setText("");
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if(ae.getSource()==submit)
        {
            try{
                showfile();
               }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception e"+ioe);
            }
        }
        else if(ae.getSource()==exit)
             {
            System.exit(0);
             }
    }

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        new filecontent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println("Exception e : "+ioe);`, put `ioe.printStackTrace()` and show us what it prints. Also, looks like you're confused between `NullPointerException` and `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: So are you getting `NullPointerException` or `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: @adarshr : printStackTrace() shows that error is on : **fin[i]=new FileReader(t[i].getText());**. I am getting FileNotFoundException...I don't understand what is wrong with  the above line.It gets text from TextFiled, that should be ok.so what is wrong actually?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a NullPointerException. You have a FileNotFoundException. As the name of this exceptions says this is because a file you try to open isn't found.

The first file access that fails is this one:

```
FileReader fn=new FileReader("filecontent.java");
```

If your java file is located within a src (or any other) folder of your project you have to add the folder. E.g. `src/filecontent.java`

Some other notes:

- By convention java class names start with upper case letters
- Your variable names `t, ta, p1, etc.` can be confusing. Why not use `textFields, textAreas, panel`?
- I think you will run into an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this line `while(cnt<=4)`
  . Array indices start with 0 and end with n - 1 (=3 in your case)
- It can help debuging to print out the stacktrace in your catch block: `ioe.printStackTrace()`. This gives you the exact line number where your code fails

Comment: thank you for your advise.I tried ioe.printStackTrace(); and it shows error on below line :   
 **fin[i]=new FileReader(t[i].getText());**

Comment: looks like t[i].getText() does not contain a valid filename.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception may have come from this line

```
FileReader fn=new FileReader("filecontent.java");
```

I think you should use a full path, not just a file name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why don't you use FileDialog instead of textField for the file. Secondly, you are using relative path so for your program to work, the file filecontent.java must be in the same place as your .class file

Answer (score 0):

When reading a file in java the syntax for filepath varies system to system. So you should apply the path according to the operating system you are using.
Also for your code the file **filecontent.java** should be in the same directory.

Comment: filecontent.java is the file in which this code is.so i dnt think problem related to path arises.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, the answer is that the file appears as `a.txt` in explorer but is actually `a.txt.txt`  Showing file extensions in explorer avoids this issue/confusion.

---

When you use a file path it is relative to the working directory, i.e. where the application was run.  Not where the source code can be found. If you don't know what your working directory is, you should use a full path name.

Comment: The file is not where you think it is or the full path name is not correct. Can you do `DIR full-path-name` for example?

Comment: But when you do `System.out.println(new File("path").exists());` you get `false`? You are not using single back slashes by any chance? ;)

Comment: It returns false.But i wonder...path was "F:/Java/Programs/core java/IO/a.txt". do you see anything syntactically wrong?  by the way thanks.at least I come to know that something wrong with path.

Comment: Can you check `System.out.println(new File("F:/Java/Programs/core java/IO/").exists());` Keep removing parts of the path until it returns true. You could have a problem with the directory with a space in the name.

Comment: Actually I gave file a name "**a.txt**" which is text file.So whole name became "**a.txt.txt**".Now I changed name to "**a**". So it returns true with above path.

Comment: For this reason I always show file extensions instead of hiding them. ;)